# The factors that should match for a couple to live a happy life?

Tags: marriage, astrology, horoscopes

In Hinduism, what all horoscope poruthams (matching factors) are required for a couple to get married? Please let me know the minimum criteria ?
If the horoscopes don't match properly, are there any remedies for such situations i.e., some special poojas that may help in overcoming the doshas?

Comment: @SreeCharan i simply added love ,bcoz i consider love as primary and important factor for happy life between a successfully man and women

Comment: Matching of atleast 18 Gunas out of 36 without any Doshas is generally considered good.

Comment: @TheDestroyer what are these gunas

Comment: AshtaKoota is just one. I recently visited an old astrologer to get matching done for someone. He used atleast 10 different methods to do so and averaged out the result. So, I think the answer will very from astrologer to astrologer. It would be good to know techniques other than AshtaKoota, that are used. Even AshtaKoota is very involved. If someone knows about that in detail, would love to learn that too.

Comment: and what does this question have to do with Hindu religion? Astrology is a separate discipline of Indian culture, not part of the Hindu religion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda agreed ,but where should i ask this question else, i think Hinduism is the best place for my doubt

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Please see the discussion on meta [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/72/2995).

Comment: The matching is different for brahmins and non-brahmins. Points matching is followed for non-brahmins where was internal aspects of the jAtakam is studied and matched for brahmins

Comment: @moonstar2001 did u know match making for brahmins

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*For beginners it is recommended to use an online [Match Calculator](https://www.vedastro.org/match),
that use Ashta-Kuta system and takes into account the exceptions.*

Matchmaking is the process of matching two  persons together, usually for the purpose of marriage **Based on Gunas or Marks** , Which is done with the help of  [**Panchanga**](http://www.datepanchang.com/) along with  Match **Making Charts** . Kundali matchmaking of a prospective bride and groom is the only option to ensure their compatibility. In **Ashta-Kuta system** of match making, the maximum number of Gunas are 36.
**Eight main factors** Commonly seen in matchmaking are -:

> 1. Varna (वर्ण)
> 2. Vashya (वश्य)
> 3. Tara (तारा)
> 4. Yoni (योनी)
> 5. Grah Maitri (ग्रह मैत्री)
> 6. Gana Rashikuta Or GanaGunaChakra गण राशि कूट , गण गुण चक्र
> 7. Naadi OR Nadi Guna (नाडी ,नाडी गुण)
> 8. SadSatKuta (सदसत कूट)

Each factor is assigned basic points, which are as follows -
 (Varna is 1 point), (Vashya is 2 points), (Tara  is 3 points), (Yoni is 4 points), (Graha Maitri is 5 points), (Gana  Rashikuta is 6 points) Sadsat kuta 7 points and (Naadi  maximum  8 points.) The summation of all these points is 36.

On these parameters, the Kundali of the two interested person's are matched and the result of that calculations is called Guna Matching (गुण मिलन) (Match Making)

> Out of total 36 points,18 points  is 50%, are considered average, and
> 28 is considered to be satisfactory. Minimum 18 points are needed for
> matching the Kundli's.18 to 24    AVERAGE SCORE.      Wedding match is acceptable.
> 25 to 32    VERY GOOD MATCH. Marriage will be a success.
> 33 to 36    EXCELLENT MATCH. Marriage will  be a complete  success.

When the  bride and the groom have the same Naadi, (Madhya , Antya ,Aadya मध्य ,अन्त्य ,आद्य) it is called as Naadi Dosha. For eg, when **both** of them have Madhya Naadi, the Naadi Dosha will create  some problems. This has a direct connection with blood groups of the couple involved.

> There are eight types of Doshas -:
>
> 1. Nrudrur Dosha न्रुदुर दोष
> 2. Janma nakshtra Dosha जन्म नक्षत्र दोष
> 3. Ek charan Dosha एक चरण दोष
> 4. Yoni maitri Dosha योनी मैत्री
> 5. Graha Maitri Dosha ग्रह मैत्री दोष
> 6. Manushya Rakashasa Dosha मनुष्य राक्षस दोष
> 7. Kuta Dosha कूट दोष
> 8. Ek Nadi Dosha एक नाडी दोष

All over India, for Kundali matchmaking **Mangal Dosha** is seriously taken into account. While Shani Dosha is not seriously considered by all astrologers. Rashi(Moon signs).

---

**If horoscopes don't match properly are there any remedies for such situations ie, some special poojas that may help in overcoming the doshas?**

There are some remedies for above situation's which includes performing various Shanti's in consultation with a  expert  Astrologer ,as it depends upon case to case.So it's always safe to consult a priest or acharya before  doing such poojas even told by astrologer.
 This answer is based on [**Date** **panchanga Hard-Copy**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFAGu.jpg)
 
 **IMP** **Note** - This is general Match Making or Guna Milan. The comprehensive Match Making is complex & is a detail procedure.**

---

**These are Match Making Charts or Tables**
[image]
[image]

Comment: @sv. - Thanks , I have revised the answer , correction's done as suggested :)

Comment: Nice answer..what is "date panchang hard copy"? r u referring to some book?

Comment: @Rickross - It's panchanga only but in Hard-Copy format with me Full.E-Panchaga is not avaliable ,it came in book only.

Comment: @SreepathySp Maybe you can award your bounty to this answer since you already accepted it?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar What about the score in between like 24.5, 32.5 etc., Grading falls on left or right?

Comment: ***"....the Naadi Dosha will create some problems. This has a direct connection with blood groups of the couple involved."*** - What are the exact, **scriptural sources** and maybe scientific sources too, for this blood group claim in your answer, dear @SwiftPushkar, please elucidate?

Answer (score 2):

Horoscope Matching basically consider 8 things and try to match between male & female's horoscope. As you might have read in [Panchang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam), the most basic things which decides the Guna Matching between two horoscope is Nakshatra.

Below is attached Nakshtra Table, which helps you to decide the ashta guna between boy's and Girl's Horoscope.
[image]

Now talking about the Ashta Guna, There are 8 factors which decides the Guna Matching between boy's and Girl's Horoscope.

1. Varna
2. Vashya
3. Tara
4. Yoni
5. Grah Maitri
6. Gana Rashikuta
7. Naadi
8. Sad Sat Kuta

You can check these 8 factors in detail while doing [horoscope matching](https://astrolaabh.in/horoscope-matching) with your partner. But overall, it is the nakshtra, which decides the horoscope matching's Guna Milan.

Answer (score 0):

Many so called modern astrologers don’t take enough care while matching horoscope for marriage. In my view following are the factors should be considered while matching two horoscope,

1. Matching according to Nakshatara. There are several matching that need to be considered 
   a) Dina
   b) Gana
   c) Mahendra
   d) Stree Deergha
   e) Yoni
   f) Rasi
   g) Rasi Adhipati
   h) Vasiya
   i) Rajju
   J) Vedha
   K) Varna 
   l) Nadi
2. 7th house(Marriage life) and 7th lord placement, aspection, conjunction
3. 8th house(Mangalaya sthana), 8th lord placement, aspection and conjunction
4. 2nd house(Family life), 2nd lord placement, aspection and conjunction
5. 5th house(children), 5th lord placement, aspection and conjunction. When people matched without analyzing 5th house, they will have problem in getting children
6. Beja and Khestra sthana and its lord - To find whether couples will get children
7. Any relation between 7th, 2nd and 12th lord. When someone have combined affliction in these houses they might get separated after marriage.
8. Dasa Bukti of both boy and girl, need to check if both have any common bad periods
9. What is the dosha percentage between Boy and girl. Ex: Kuja Dosha, Rahu/Ketu dosha etc

When astrologer give importance to all these factors, then couple will lead happy life after marriage.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Thanks for your answer but advertizing is not allowed on Hinduism SE! Such answers may be downvoted or deleted altogether.